# what is the advantage/disadvantage in each way to update a lot of documents in Couchbase, Java SDK?

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

i have sometimes the need to update many documents at once, 10K or even more, and I am thinking what is the advantage/disadvantage in each way?

I thought of two ways to do it, and I will happy to understand what is advantage/disadvantage and to to hear on a third way.

i am looking for a good batch way to do this.

way 1, send to observable to get all the documents and do the work:

```
Observable
            .from(ids)
            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<JsonDocument> call(String id) {
                    return bucket.async().get(id);
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<JsonDocument, JsonDocument>() {
                @Override
                public JsonDocument call(JsonDocument original) {
                    // do some change in the document content
                    original.content().put("add", "content");
                    return original;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<JsonDocument> call(JsonDocument modified) {
                    return bucket.async().replace(modified);
                }
            }).subscribe();
```

way 2, run on each document id and use async get and then change the document async way:

```
for (String id : ids){
        bucket.async()
                .get(id)
                .map(new Func1<JsonDocument, JsonDocument>() {
                    @Override
                    public JsonDocument call(JsonDocument jsonDocument) {
                    // do some change in the document content
                        jsonDocument.content().put("add", "content");
                        return jsonDocument;
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<JsonDocument> call(JsonDocument modified) {
                        return bucket.async().replace(modified);
                    }
                }).subscribe();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could use a little perf benchmarking, but I think both approaches are fine and should be relatively close in performance.

Using `bucket.async()` in both case ensure that internally, the requests will rapidly be queued in the ringBuffer and fired to the server.

A 3rd way would have been similar to option 2 but with blocking API, and that would definitely perform worse.

All in all, option 1 is purely Rx and, although a little overhead may occur in `Observable.from`, maybe it provides the most coherent readability so I'd use this one. Plus you get a single stream and subscription, so you pay the overhead just once.

Comment: in option 2 when I don't have a document I expect to get null but the process ends, what should I do?

Comment: You can try to chain a defaultIfEmpty(null) after the get I think